# Request input null in Laravel Controller

Tags: ajax, laravel, controller, request

**Hi I have a problem with getting the value of input using request in Controller, it's always return null. This is my code in jquery I am using Ajax to pass value to controller.**

```
$('.generate').click(function(){

    var dstart =  $("#datepickerstart").val();
    var dend =  $("#datepickerend").val();
   
  
      //var empid = $('#empid').val();
      if($('#empid').val().length == 0)
      {
        empid = 0;

      }
      else{

        empid = $('#empid').val();
      }
     

    
   
    var dStart = 0;
    var dEnd = 0;
    //alert(empid);
    $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "{{route('manageattendance', '')}}"+"/"+empid,
          data:$('#attendanceform').serialize(),
    
          success: function(response)
            {
              console.log(response);
            // alert("data caught");
            $('.content').load('manageattendance/'+empid); 
            },  
          error: function(error)
            {
               console.log(error);
             //alert("not caught ");
             // alert($('#editForm').serialize());
            } 
    
     });
    //alert(dstart);
    //alert(dend);
});
```

**And this is my code in controller. I am trying to get the data using request but it returns null when I checked it. What would be the cause? Please help me. Thanks**

```
 public function index($id = 0,Request $request)
    {
    

        if($id == 0){
           
          
           $current_date = date('Y-m-d');
           $attendances = Attendance::select('Name','CheckIn','CheckOut','Note','Date','TotalHours')- 
>where('Date','=',$current_date)->get();
            //$start = '2021-02-10';
            //$end = '2021-02-11';
           

            //$attendances = 
Attendance::select('Name','CheckIn','CheckOut','Note','Date','TotalHours')->whereBetween('Date', 
[$start,$end])->get();
            return view('manage.index',compact('attendances'));
        }
      
        else
        {
            $start = $request->input('datepickerstart');
            $end = $request->input('datepickerend');
            $newS = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start));
            $newE = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($end));
            



            $sUser = User::select('name')->where('id','=',$id)->get();
            //$attendances = 
Attendance::select('Name','CheckIn','CheckOut','Note','Date','TotalHours')->where('user_id','=',$id)- 
>get();
            $attendances = 
Attendance::select('Name','CheckIn','CheckOut','Note','Date','TotalHours')->whereBetween('Date', 
 [$start,$end])->get();
            return view('manage.index',compact('attendances','sUser'));
           // dd($start);
        }

     
       // return view('manage.index');
     
    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    }
```

Comment: Anyone? Please help me

Comment: Could you please share you route `manageattendance`?

Answer (score 0):

don't forget **{{csrf_field }}** in form and put **id** in **input** name is **id**

```
$('.generate').click(function(){

    var dstart =  $("#datepickerstart").val();
    var dend =  $("#datepickerend").val();
   
  
      //var empid = $('#empid').val();
      if($('#empid').val().length == 0)
      {
        empid = 0;

      }
      else{

        empid = $('#empid').val();
      }
     

    
   
    var dStart = 0;
    var dEnd = 0;
    //alert(empid);
    $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "{{route('manageattendance.update')}}"+"/"+empid,
          data:$('#attendanceform').serialize(),
    
          success: function(response)
            {
              console.log(response);
            // alert("data caught");
            $('.content').load('manageattendance/'+empid); 
            },  
          error: function(error)
            {
               console.log(error);
             //alert("not caught ");
             // alert($('#editForm').serialize());
            } 
    
     });
    //alert(dstart);
    //alert(dend);
});
```

---

```
 public function index(Request $request)
    {
    

        if(request->id == 0){
           
          
           $current_date = date('Y-m-d');
           $attendances = Attendance::select('Name','CheckIn','CheckOut','Note','Date','TotalHours')- 
>where('Date','=',$current_date)->get();
            //$start = '2021-02-10';
            //$end = '2021-02-11';
           

            //$attendances = 
Attendance::select('Name','CheckIn','CheckOut','Note','Date','TotalHours')->whereBetween('Date', 
[$start,$end])->get();
            return view('manage.index',compact('attendances'));
        }
      
        else
        {
            $start = $request->input('datepickerstart');
            $end = $request->input('datepickerend');
            $newS = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start));
            $newE = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($end));
            



            $sUser = User::select('name')->where('id','=',$request->id)->get();
            $attendances = 
Attendance::select('Name','CheckIn','CheckOut','Note','Date','TotalHours')->where('user_id','=',$request->id)->whereBetween('Date', 
 [$start,$end])- 
>get();
           
            return view('manage.index',compact(['attendances'=>$attendances,'sUser'=>$sUser]));
           // dd($start);
        }

     
       
    }
```

Comment: Yes I have {{csrf_field }} in my form, but the input value which inside the form is null when it goes to controller.

Comment: @KletoRalphFuentesSalvo ajax code inside blade page or external js file ?